# Cleaning up xaml with regex

Tags: regex, xaml, visual-studio-2012, replace

I am working on some xaml that is cluttered. The Label's have their own `name` and `TabIndex`, which are both unnecessary in my situation. Take the following example Label element,

```
<Label Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="40" x:Name="Page2Label15" Width="40" TabIndex="40">Great Label</Label>
```

How can I use Visual Studio 2012 (or another xaml editor) to remove the unwanted `name` and `TabIndex` attributes without targeting false positives? By false positives, I mean something like the below that I need to preserve.

```
<TextBox Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="40" x:Name="Page2Textbox15" Width="70" TabIndex="40">Great Label</TextBox>
```

It seems like this should be possible, because the VS 2012 Find and Replace allows for the use of regular expressions. I have had trouble getting the [look around regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/299327) to work correctly.

I would like the end result to be:

```
<Label Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="40" Width="40">Great Label</Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the regex capabilities of visual studio, but you can try this search/replace:

```
search:  (<Label [^>]+?)(?:(?:x:Name|TabIndex)="[^"]*")([^>]*?)(?:(?:x:Name|TabIndex)="[^"]*")([^>]*>)
replace: $1$2$3      or      \1\2\3
```

The idea is to capture all the content of the label tags that are not attributes you want to remove and then replace only with the captured strings.

EDIT: it seems that this pattern works only when the two ugly attributes are present.
You can remove the cases with an only one attribute with:

```
search:  (<Label [^>]+?)(?:(?:x:Name|TabIndex)="[^"]*")
replace: $1
```

(or use this only pattern twice)

Notice: You can try these patterns with notepad++ (take the last version)

Comment: Unfortunately VS 2012 regex doesn't seem to like it. Do you know of another editor or script that this will work for?

Comment: @RyanGates: I suggest you to test these patterns with notepad++

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me with Notepad++ 6.3.2 (UNICODE).

Comment: Notepad++  Uses a regular Regex Engine.  Visual Studio has a special engine for it's search/replace matching.  Please see my example.  My example will not work in Notepad or RegexBuddy or anywhere else except Visual Studio Search/Replace... which as I understand it is where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio uses a very special Regular Expression engine.  I'm not talking about the .Net Framework, I mean the actual VS GUI.  It's sorta gross.

[Visual Studio Regex Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Anyway... try something like this...

```
{\<Label[^\>]*}(x\:Name|TabIndex)=:q
Replace with \1
```

You'd have to run it twice.

If I read correctly, `:q` should match everything in quotes, including the quotes.  Also, you can use Parenthesis as sub-expressions, but Capture-Groups are actually with Curly-Braces, which are typically quantifiers in normal Regex.  Very odd.  Lastly, the Colon, and GT/LT symbols are special characters, so I had to escape all of those.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work in VS 2012? I could not get it working.

Comment: I am still not having any luck with the new version.

Comment: I added the `?` at the last second as a Regex habit... turns out VS doesn't like that.  Copy/Paste it now.